# biblatex chem-acs: Including Issue Number

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I've been able to include article titles and DOIs, which are optional in ACS style, in citations using

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,articletitle=true,doi=true]{biblatex}
```

Is there a way to also include the issue number, preferably in this same line?

e.g. I have

```
@article{clusters,
    author   = {Johnathan P.K. Doyle and David J. Wales and Mark A. Miller},
    title    = {Thermodynamics and the Global Optimization of Lennard-Jones Clusters},
    journal  = {J. Chem. Phys.},
    date     = {1998},
    volume   = {109},
    number   = {19},
    pages = {8143-8153},
    doi = {10.1063/1.477477},
}
```

in my `.bib` giving

[image]

I'm looking to include *109* (19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chem-acs` redefines the bibmacro `volume+number+eid` to get rid of the `number` ([ll. 273-277 in v1.1y [2019/12/03]](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/blob/c69afe4bc8c8d1faa8365717d573457e7e72f098/chem-acs.bbx#L273-L277)), but we can add it back in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs, articletitle=true, doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{clusters,
  author   = {Johnathan P.K. Doyle and David J. Wales and Mark A. Miller},
  title    = {Thermodynamics and the Global Optimization of Lennard-Jones Clusters},
  journal  = {J. Chem. Phys.},
  date     = {1998},
  volume   = {109},
  number   = {19},
  pages    = {8143-8153},
  doi      = {10.1063/1.477477},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{clusters}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Doyle, J. P.; Wales, D. J.; Miller, M. A. Thermodynamics and the Global Optimization of Lennard-Jones Clusters. J. Chem. Phys. 1998, 109 (19),8143–8153, DOI: 10.1063/1.477477.]