# biblatex chem-acs: get a point instead of a comma between pages and doi

Tags: citing, biblatex-chem

I've been using the example from here ([biblatex chem-acs: Including Issue Number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565292/biblatex-chem-acs-including-issue-number?newreg=f7d388297d2d446c8d9c86bc0806481b)) to get journal article citations as in the ACS quick style guide.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs, articletitle=true, doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
 \printfield{volume}%
 \setunit*{\addspace}%
 \printfield{number}%
 \setunit*{\addspace}%
 \printfield{eid}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{clusters,
 author   = {Johnathan P.K. Doyle and David J. Wales and Mark A. Miller},
 title    = {Thermodynamics and the Global Optimization of Lennard-Jones Clusters},
 journal  = {J. Chem. Phys.},
 date     = {1998},
 volume   = {109},
 number   = {19},
 pages    = {8143-8153},
 doi      = {10.1063/1.477477},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{clusters}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which gives me the this output in my `.bib`:
[image]

but i would like to have a dot between the pages and the doi instead of the comma and i would also like to remove the dot after the doi:

like ....8143-8153. DOI: 10.1063/1.477477

I would be very thankful for any advice on how i can achieve this!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redefine the **bibmacro** `doi+eprint+url` by manually inserting a **dot** and a **space** with `\printunit{\adddot\addspace}` in front of the command which calls the **DOI**. This should override the standard punctuation of your used style in most cases. Additionally to `artcile` I tested it for `book`, as you see below. It inserts a **dot** in front of the **DOI** in both cases.

Just test it with the edited MWE. For me, it works so far:

```latex
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs, articletitle=true, doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{eid}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @article{clusters,
        author   = {Johnathan P.K. Doyle and David J. Wales and Mark A. Miller},
        title    = {Thermodynamics and the Global Optimization of Lennard-Jones Clusters},
        journal  = {J. Chem. Phys.},
        date     = {1998},
        volume   = {109},
        number   = {19},
        pages    = {8143-8153},
        doi      = {10.1063/1.477477},
    }
    
    @book{bernal2001,
        author    = {Bernal, Martin},
        editor    = {Moore, David Chioni},
        publisher = {Duke University Press},
        title     = {Black Athena Writes Back},
        year      = {2001},
        address   = {New York},
        subtitle  = {Martin Bernal Responds to His Critics},
        url = {https://www.wikipedia.org/},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\iffieldundef{doi}{}{\printunit{\adddot\addspace}}
        \printfield{doi}
        \ifboolexpr{    (not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}
                        and
                        test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}
                        and
                        test {\iffieldundef{url}}
                        and
                        test {\iffieldundef{addendum}}
                        and
                        test {\iffieldundef{pubstate}}
                        and
                        test {\iffieldundef{related}})
                    }{\nopunct}{}
    }
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
    Lorem \autocite{clusters}
    
    Lorem \autocite{bernal2001}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

To achieve, as asked by the OP, that there is no dot after the DOI, I added a new redefinition of the `doi+eprint+url` macro. With two more or less complex **boolexpr** it tests if the field `doi` is defined and if all following fields are undefined. If `doi` is defined, it inserts a preceding dot instead of a comma, but keeps it (resp. more precise `\newblockpunct` which results in a comma for this style) otherwise. Furthermore, if all following fields are undefined, it ends the bibentry without any punctuation. But if a field follows after the `doi` (e.g. `url`) it keeps the standard behaviour of inserting a comma between the two fields.

To be honest, I'm not sure if there may be a simpler code solution. But I tested it with several entries containing different field variations and, at least, it worked quite good.

Comment: Thank you vary much for your help. This resolves part of the issue i have: The comma after the pages is substituted by a dot but the dot after the doi is still there. I only want a dot after the pages but no dot after doi. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: O, must have overlooked this part. I'll come back to you, as soon as I'm back at my desk ;)

Comment: I kind of got it to work but not with an elegant solution: I added `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}` to remove the dot from all citations and when i have a citation without doi i just add `\adddot` to the pages entry of the `.bib`. If you could come up with a clean solution that would still be very much appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry, it took some time. But see my edit and the updated redefinition of the `bibmacro`.

Comment: Great that achieved exactly what i intended to do. Thank you so much for your time, super nice of you! Have a great day.

Comment: Happy I could help :)